# Unicode characters (Cyrillic) with Intel Fortran

Tags: unicode, fortran

Does anyone have any experience with using Unicode in Fortran? How does one pass Cyrillic characters, and open files with Cyrillic characters in their names?

Details:

I have a Fortran executable that needs to read parameters from a control file. Some of these parameters are in Cyrillic (e.g., file paths).

The executable calls a C++ DLL. Some of the parameters to these calls need to be in Cyrillic.

I am using the latest Intel Fortran.

I'm looking for any source of information, or small examples as to how to do so.

Comment: The correct answer is "Yes", but I suspect that you *actually* wanted to ask a different question than the one you wrote down.

Comment: There are three questions in there. Are you saying you want more detail?

Comment: What 3 questions? I *honestly* don't see them! You ask if someone has experience and don't ask about anything **specifically**. "passing Cyrillic characters in and out" is not a question. What are you asking? "Does it work?", "What do I need to do to make it work?", "What am I doing wrong if *foo* happens?" or something else entirely?

Comment: I see my elaboration was edited out -- will try to re-add.

Comment: Wow, what an exotic question!  Very very cool.  I’d be delighted to learn the answer myself, just for curiosity’s sake.  Note that handling Unicode in datastreams and handling Unicode names in the filesystem are actually wholly distinct concerns, and always have different answers.

Comment: The main problem is the lack of a native Unicode string datatype in Fortran; I've seen samples converting MCBS to Unicode, but the target datatype for that is INTEGER(). Neat... and then what?

Comment: @Stu - Sorry Stu about the edit. I could've swore the lower part of the text wasn't there when I edited it. (?!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already indicated, Fortran 2003 has a Unicode character type.   Exactly what features will work with that character type ... I don't know ... filenames?  I don't see mention of Unicode in the release notes for the Intel Fortran compiler.   In 2006 Intel indicated that this feature was a low priority (http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=51751).   You might ask on the Intel forums ... probably an Intel representative will answer about the capabilities of the Intel compiler.  If the Intel Fortran compiler can't handle Unicode yet, you might need to do this I/O in another language.

Comment: F2008 specifies that the FILE= specifier of the OPEN statement must be of type character with default kind, so no UCS-4 characters there I'm afraid. That being said, while the default character for backwards compatibility reasons needs to be ASCII-compatible, I don't think there's anything preventing the compiler from interpreting them as e.g. UTF-8 in the OPEN statement.

Comment: Thanks. As I suspected, SOL for my specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

While I've not done anything similar, so have no personal experience on the matter, simply googling "fortran unicode" shows a few interesting results.

Apparently, [gfortran has some moderate support for it](http://www.groupsrv.com/computers/about681239.html) (for an example scroll a bit down).  Also, Tobian Burnus's answer [in this thread sheds some more light on the matter](http://www.groupsrv.com/computers/about681239.html) - it seems that there is progress on that field, in F2003 and the (upcoming) F2013 standard, but for now, it doesn't really present one of the priorities.

Comment: I found those as well -- but I'm using Intel's compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open unicode files, this will not help.  However, by default, the Intel Fortran compiler cannot even open files in a unicode folder.  The documentation doesn't make it clear, but the `/fpscomp:general` compiler flag will allow you to work within unicode folders.

Comment: Nope. I just opened a file "тест/тест.txt" read the string from there string and printed it in Intel Fortan v 16. the output was "Система формализованных заданий, по резуль
 татам выполнения к-рых можно судить об уров
 не развития определённых качеств испытуем�
 �го, а также о его знаниях, умениях и навыках
 . " So yes, it has some problem with one character, but that may also be because of the source I pasted it from. It has no problem with opening Unicode directories. Maybe Windows has problems with them, but not Intel Fortran.